# How do I change a Polar plot to be completely smooth and have a taper to the line width?

Tags: plotting

Trying to taper the line in a smooth polar plot but keep line spacing the same.  How can this be done in Mathematica 13?

Here's the basic code I'm working from:

```
PolarPlot[theta/2 Pi, {theta, 0, 280 Pi}, Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, Background -> White, ImageSize -> {4000, 2000}]
```

This produces a very linear plot where you can see each segment.  I need something completely smooth.  Also need the white space to be a constant value and the black line taper from a starting value to the ending value.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Add `PlotPoints -> 300, MaxRecursion -> 7`

Comment: Thanks, @Bob Hanlon.  This completely smooths the lines.   Much much better!  How can the line width be changed to thinner at the beginning and thicker at the end and still keep a certain amount of white space?

Comment: Break the plot range `{theta, 0, 280 Pi}` into segments. Plot each segment with a different `PlotStyle` and combine all of the plots with `Show`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Hmm, can that prodduce a smooth taper to the spiral line?  Probably a programatical way to create the segments to keep it smooth would work I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]Here's the workaround to taper a spiral Polar plot using Rescale and MeshShading:

```
PolarPlot[theta/2 Pi, {theta, 0, 20 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 300,PlotStyle ->Black, Mesh -> {Range[0, 20 Pi, 0.01]},MeshStyle -> None,MeshShading ->(Directive[ AbsoluteThickness[Rescale[#, {0, 20 Pi}, {1, 10}]]] & /@ 
Range[0, 20 Pi, 0.01]), MaxRecursion -> 15, Axes -> None,PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Just noticed a typo in `MeshShading -(Directive` should of course be `MeshShading ->(Directive`.

Comment: Thanks, Good catch!

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[variableThicknessCurve]
variableThicknessCurve[x_, range_: {0, 2 Pi}] := Module[{f = BSplineFunction[x]},
 FilledCurve[{Line[Reverse @ x], 
    Line[f[#] + Rescale[#, {0, 1}, range] Cross @ Normalize[f'[#]] & /@ 
      Subdivide[Length @ x]]}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
pp = PolarPlot[theta/2 Pi, {theta, 0, 20 Pi}, Axes -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Black, Background -> White, ImageSize -> 600, PlotPoints -> 1000];
```

Post-process `pp` to replace the `Line` object with `variableThicknessCurve`:

```
ReplaceAll[Line[x_] :> variableThicknessCurve[x]] @ pp
```

[image]

Use `variableThicknessCurve[x, {2, 7}]`  to get

[image]

Use `variableThicknessCurve[x, {7, 1}]` to make the line progressivly thinner:

[image]

Use `ReplaceAll[Line[x_] :>{RadialGradientFilling[{Red, Blue}], variableThicknessCurve[x]}]@pp` to get

[image]